# Is there any way to change browser autocomplete visuals on angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, input-field

I am having a problem with angular material when I try to select an option saved by the browser in an input field.

[image: empty input field]

[image: input field with option selected from autocomplete]

[image: filled input field]

As you can see, there is a white rectangle around the text. Is there any way to remove it and make the text appear without it?

Comment: Can you provide an example with https://stackblitz.com/ ? Because this is not the intended design from Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)

Comment: @Wandrille https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-exj1vw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
 ::ng-deep input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}
```

input:-webkit-autofill is the selector you need to use to "override" the User Agent style applied automagically by "webkit".

However, seems to be "bugged" because it doesn't accept a background-color: transparent, so the trick I have been used is to create a transition this way.

Comment: Yes. It is working... kinda. Now, what should I do if, let's say, I want to change the text color because by default it's black? Also, does this work for all browsers?

Comment: Kinda? Anything not working? Just to help you with that. To change the color of the “input” just add a color style in the input selector. This “webkit-autofill” is a color added by Webkit browsers as Safari and Chrome. Please try the solution and report any issues with other browsers.

Comment: I'm saying this because, if I try to add something or make any change after I use the autocomplete option, the text changes to default color, white, from black. I don't know if there are any other problems, but I will check. Also, is this an angular material problem?

Comment: Nope. This is a Style that Webkit browsers applies to any input in a form which has been autofilled because it was previously saved (credit card, user-password, etc) so the Users know the browser has filled the field automagically for them.

Comment: Regarding text colors. Apply input { color: black !important} and add color: black !important to the special selector in my answer too.

Comment: Updated the answer. With -webkit-text-fill-color it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work for my material input until I removed  ::ng-deep